# Customize control strip in Keynote

Tags: touch-bar

I'd like to add the View->Light Table button on the touch bar.  Is this possible? 
I've been trying to find a way, but no success until now.

Answer (score 1):

Keynote doesn't have a "Customize Touch Bar" option in the menu bar under "View", so it looks there is no way to customize it (macOS Mojave).

Comment: There is no option "Customize Touch Bar" (Keynote 9.1). Only thing I see is "Customize Tool Bar" which customizes the tool bar of the window.

Comment: Good catch @jendas, updated answer.